# How does apt-get deal with multiple sources?

Tags: package-management, apt

Let's say Ubuntu's repositories features a package.

I install that package using `apt-get`.

I then add an additional source (with `add-apt-repository`) that lists either a newer or older version of the package.

Will apt-get always upgrade to the latest version, regardless of which source offers the latest version?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

APT will always install the latest version that isn't excluded by [preferences](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences). Preferences are indicated in the file `/etc/apt/preferences` (and in files under `/etc/apt/preferences.d`).

Some repositories have a configuration that prevents their packages from being installed automatically. For example, the Debian backports have release files (which you can see in `/var/lib/apt/lists`) that contain

```
NotAutomatic: yes
ButAutomaticUpgrades: yes
```

If you have multiple sources for the exact same package (i.e. same package name, same version number), then APT downloads from the first source found in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`; the files are searched in lexicographic order, and the sources are searched in order inside each file). So list local mirrors first. The order in `sources.list` is irrelevant for packages that have a different version number.

Comment: so for the exact same package (same name, same version number), apt will search in alphabetical order in `sources.list.d` (and it's sub directories)?

Comment: @Sajuuk In `sources.list` first, then in the files in `sources.list.d` in alphabetical order. Inside each file, it searches in the order the sources are listed in the file.

Comment: I know, because sources can exist in multiple location, such as /etc/apt/sources.list, and ./etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list  I'm asking in what order would those sources be searched?

Comment: @Sajuuk See my edited comment (I'd pressed Enter before I'd finished typing it).

Comment: super tangential, but people, please don't start your setting/variable/etc names with "not". that adds unnecessary logic for everyone.